# Print all local variables in Golang

Tags: go

I wanted to know how one can enumerate the names and values of all local variables in golang. This is done with the purpose of effectively debugging go code.

Yes, [I am well aware golang has limited gdb support right now.](https://golang.org/doc/gdb)

This [commonly used thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430811/enumerate-or-list-all-variables-in-a-program-of-your-favorite-language-here)  has no mention of golang.

I am genuinely looking for a solution (I think others are curious as well).

Many thanks.

Comment: Short of reflecting on your stack frame, finding the code and parsing it, I doubt it is possible. Even then I'm not sure you could get their values via reflection. Just their names.

Comment: I don't think you can do it.

Comment: update: delve, a debugger for golang. is now in pre 1.0 and has osx support. its still not fully functional but its coming along. You should check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy solution:

- [`gotype`](https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/cmd/gotype) can do static analysis of the code and print all variables (but not their value)
- [`go-spew`](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew) can print a variable value (deep pretty printer for Go data structures to aid in debugging), but that is like an enhanced `printf`, not a 'gdb' like debug session.

Answer (score 2):

There is [dlv](https://github.com/derekparker/delve), you can experiment with the `print` command, it's the closest thing to a live debugger you can get atm.

Otherwise gotype/go-spew like @VonC mentioned are the way to go.

Comment: thanks. I know about dlv but it doesn't have osx support yet.